# NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for :account:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am trying to query the following

```
Vehicle.where(:account.name => "").count
```

and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for :account:Symbol
```

The associations between Vehicle and Account have been define on the model, and I user conventions. Why do I get this error?

---

Vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
end
```

Account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vehicles
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "accounts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    ...
end

create_table "vehicles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Vehicle.joins(:account).where("accounts.name = ?", "").count
```

You can also search for blank fields with:

```
Vehicle.joins(:account).where("accounts.name <> ''").count
```

Comment: I got this error Shannon> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "account"
LINE 1: ...nt_id" AND "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE (account.wf...

Comment: Updated - use plural for table name

Comment: I still get an error: Association named 'accounts' was not found on Vehicle; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Updated, should work with plural table name in `where` clause

Comment: "blank" could mean `''` or `null` so you really should `coalesce(accounts.name, '') <> ''` or `accounts.name is not null and accounts.name <> ''` instead of just `accounts.name <> ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is raise because rails is considering `account` as a column, if you want to where condition for associated table then make join between them, like following

```
Vehicle.joins('account').where("account.name IS NULL").count
```